# I want to convert Python to exe that imported tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

There was a problem with exe conversion using the pyinstaller.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Find.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hsk15\python_project\javaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hsk15\python_project\javaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
  File "lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "c:\users\hsk15\python_project\javaproject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'
[20188] Failed to execute script Find
```

this error.. i can find problem

why can not import pywrap_tensorflow? and what is pywrap_tensorflow?

Comment: A quick google search of the error message returns a bunch of results, including from this very website, have you checked all of those?

Comment: i can not find this error in google :'(

Comment: What do you mean? You can’t find any results for the error?

Comment: I've been looking really hard for it, but it's not find.

Answer (score 0):

**Pywrap tensorflow** is a wrapper for TensorFlow SWIG-generated bindings.

How to use pyinstaller:

First, install the pyinstaller using command prompt by executing
pip install pyinstaller:

Run this line in cmd:

pip install auto-py-to-exe

To open the application run this line in cmd:

auto-py-to-exe

There are few main options you need to choose:

```
Pick your .py file
Pick "One Directory" or "One File" option
Pick additional files
```

Then, open the application run this line in cmd, enter the command
pyinstaller filename.py replace the filename with your python code file.

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't solved it yet. :'(   Is there any other way?

Comment: What is your Error now?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'
[18124] Failed to execute script Find    <<<<what is pywrap_tensorflow?>>>

Comment: A minute, let me give you a substantive answer in a while.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness :) Additional tensorflow version is 2.0

Answer (score 0):

First; create a virtual environment. To do this, you should run this on cmd:

`pip install virtualenv`

And then, run this:

- `python -m venv VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT'S_NAME`
- `VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT'S_NAME/Scripts/activate`
- `pip install pyinstaller`

And then, download all the libraries that you use. For example:

- `pip install requests`
- `pip install datetime`

Move your code file to:

`VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT'S_NAME/Scripts`

Now, you can convert it using:

`pyinstaller --onefile PYTHON_FILE'S_NAME`